# Does SonarCloud's "delete branch" remove the origin branch from your repo?

Tags: git, github, sonarqube, sonarcloud

I'm using SonarCloud to quality control the code that I am writing on my open source project. I have a master (main branch) from which I have develop from which I make all of my feature branch.

SonarCloud is connected to my GitHub repo from which I can do all of my branch manipulation.

Develop is shown to be a short lived branch but I want to convert it to a long lived branch.

From the documentation that Sonar provides https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/branches/overview/ it says:

> Once a branch type has been set, it cannot be changed. Explicitly, you cannot transform a long-lived to short-lived branch, or vice-versa.

I therefore want to:

1. Delete all of the information that Sonar has about the branch.
2. Change my "long lived branch regular expression" to mark develop as long lived.
3. Get Sonar to re-analyse the code on my develop branch.

In order to do this I believe the only way is to delete the branch from Sonar BUT I don't want to delete my source code.

Can anyone confirm the functionality of this "Delete branch" feature?
i.e. Does it delete your origin repo branch?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SonarQube wont touch the actual repository. This just deletes the branch information from the SonarQube database.